# How to search for number in string with method Contains and Linq in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, contain

I create calculator which have buttons with numbers and operators for basic operation (+, -,...) and just want to filter buttons with numbers to detect when is clicked number (between 0-9). Also i put new eventhadler which convert sender to button.

I wondering what will be nice and easy way to filter the buttons with numbers (using linq)
What did i try so far is

```
if(btn.Text == btn.Text.Contains(x => x >= '0' && x <= '9')) 
    MessageBox.Show("number " + btn.Text + " is pressed!");
```

How to make upper code workable?

Comment: you want to check if the btn text contains number or not?

Comment: i want to check if btn text have numbers between 0-9 and than do action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to know is that is it a number or not do this. No LINQ is required

LINQ Way to check the numbers are between 0 and 9

```
if(yourstring.ToCharArray().Where(c=> c < '0' || c > '9').Any())
  return false;
else
 return true;
```

To check that it contains a valid number

```
double num;
if (double.TryParse(btn.Text, out num))
{
    // It's a number!
}
```

or to check less than 10 without linq

```
static bool IsLessThanTen(string str)
{
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thnx for replay but btn.text sometimes can have also word and number inside like "btn1" and i want to filter also those, so i ask for linq ...

Comment: I post the code which need to be workable, if you can make my example workable it will be highly appreciate

Comment: well linq working nice and easy thnx one more time :) .. that is what i searching for

Answer (score 5):

Here you go, for your immediate needs:

```
if(btn.Text.All(char.IsDigit))
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: thnx man but the question is how to check btn.text with contains method and linq, that mean if i have some button which have text "btn1" than char.IsDigit wan't work, and i want to make filter with just one analysing (with lambda x >= 0 && x <= 9)

Answer (score 2):

if you need to check at least one number in the button text, then use below

```
return btn.Text.Any(char.IsDigit)
```

If you writing calculator, you better check [**NCalc - Mathematical Expressions Evaluator for .NET**](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) and this [CodeProject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18880/State-of-the-Art-Expression-Evaluation)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
bool hasNumeric = yourString.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray()) > -1;
```